# How to include a # sign in a url using the \endnotes package

Tags: urls, characters, endnotes

I am trying to include a URL in my Latex document which contains a pound sign, #, in it.  If I  run it without escaping the # sign, I get an error.  If I escape it, then the escape character is printed out in the URL also.  ("`\#`" instead of "`#`")  Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
Hello World\endnote{\url{http://www.rossettiarchive.org/docs/nb0005.duke.rad.html#0.1.19}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code works OK in my system. What error do you get? What version of LaTeX system are you using?

Comment: I am using TexStudio and I get "Illegal Parameter number in definition of" then url string.  The log file says "you meant to type ## instead of # right?"

Comment: Did you get that error with the *exact* code you posted in your question?

Comment: add `\listfiles` and see what you get, it works for me and I get: *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size12.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
     url.sty    2006/04/12  ver 3.3  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  t1cmtt.fd    1999/05/25 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions

Comment: In case it turns out that it's something TeXStudio does to the `\footnote` command, say, then defining a command for typesetting the url first using `\urldef` might help.

Comment: Sorry, I must have put the wrong code in the question while I was trying to fix it.  This is a problem with the \endnote command, not the \footnote command.  \footnote works fine, but \endnote does not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you noticed, the `#` confuses TeX, because the endnotes are eventually read in as a macro replacement text.

Use `\urldef` for the problematic entry:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{url}
\urldef\rossetti\url|http://www.rossettiarchive.org/docs/nb0005.duke.rad.html#0.1.19|


\begin{document}
Hello World\endnote{\rossetti}
\end{document}
```

Alternative way: put this in the preamble

```
\newcommand\specialendnote{\begingroup\catcode`\#=12 \specialendnoteaux}
\newcommand\specialendnoteaux[1]{\endnote{#1}\endgroup}
```

and call

```
\specialendnote{\url{http://www.rossettiarchive.org/docs/nb0005.duke.rad.html#0.1.19}}
```