# Dollar sign (\$) dysfunctional in hyperref's \url{}

Tags: hyperref, urls, font-encodings

When escaping the **dollar sign** inside a `\url{}` command, as shown in my MWE, the following is displayed. (Below is what I am expecting).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\url{test \$ test}
test \$ test
\end{document}
```

[image: Showing the output of my problem.]

I do not have an idea what is causing this. I am using writeLaTeX to compile this - could that be the culprit?

Could [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64309/1549) be the answer? How would I go about implementing that solution for a dollar sign?

Comment: Why not just use `\url{test $ test}`?

Comment: @Werner, yes, of course. That works. Sorry for wasting your time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to escape a dollar symbol in a url.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\url{test$test} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: True. Just noticed. Excuse the mistake! I was so used to escaping everything else inside URL's that I just assumed I needed to escape `$` too!